# Require Justification on suppressing error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, code-analysis, checkin-policy

I using TFS to require developers to use Code Analysis through a check-in policy. If any errors are thrown, they can not check in their code.

They can, however, suppress the message and still check in. When they do so, I want to require them to supply a justification for their action. This can, however be left blank.

Is there any way to enforce this and not allow the justification to be left blank?

Comment: "They" are always doing bad thing. Either become part of them and change to "we never check in bad code" or beat "them" with a stick till "they" are happy... Not really clear what part of your post is related to code - changes are always in source control so it is clear when someone cheated. So why not to assume that developers don't cheat and be done with it?

Comment: I never said "they" we're doing bad things. I am simply implying that programmers can be lazy and by requiring them to fill in a simple comment explaining the reason for suppresion, I can later check why they suppressed these errors. If I allow them to suppress the error, what is the point of even showing these errors? I want to acchieve some sort of "correct" code, which can automatically be enforced through this code analysis. But then again, if they suppress the error shown, I want to know why. So please, do you know any way to get this configured?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is... You could write your own though. If you look at the TFS Power Tools they have added a few extra check-in policies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181281(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom Code Analysis rule to check for missing or empty justifications.  There's an example at http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/ex_specifysuppressmessagejustification.html.

Comment: Which can then be suppressed so it will not search for other justifications?

Comment: Yes, but only with a justification. ;)  On a somewhat more serious note, if you care about the justifications, they should included in manual code reviews, so a rule like this is really just a filter for very obvious problems.

Comment: No, not with a Justification because you can suppress the newly implemented Justificationrule, allowing SuppressMessages to be without a Justification all over again. A rule like this is kind of absolete, because this brings the same problem as all other Code Analysis errors; they can be Suppressed causing them to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up a build server and use gated check-ins. Then set the build definition to always run code analysis. If the code analysis fails, then the build would fail (if that is setup in our projects), and the check-in would not happen until they fix the code analysis, which cause the build to fail.

Comment: As stated earlier, you can suppress these errors, allowing the program to build and skipping the errors you have suppressed. So this really isn't an option because I already enforce a code analysis through TFS.